# React JS - Proper way to show the values from json array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a requirement to fetch and show the values in the form text box. I need to check whether if the value exists and not equal to null then show the values in the text box otherwise show a blank field.

The existing code implementation shows something like this :

```
 {
this.state.testJson.Names ? this.state.testJson.Names.length > 0 ? this.state.testJson.Names.map(response =>
<div className="form-group col-md-3" key={response.nameId}>
    <label htmlFor="firstName">{Liferay.Language.get('first-name')}</label>
    <input name="firstName" value={response.otherName} type="text" className="form-control" id="firstName" />
</div>
):
<div className="form-group col-md-3">
    <label htmlFor="firstName">{Liferay.Language.get('first-name')}</label>
    <input name="firstName" value='' type="text" className="form-control" id="firstName" />
</div> :
<div className="form-group col-md-3">
    <label htmlFor="firstName">{Liferay.Language.get('first-name')}</label>
    <input name="firstName" value='' type="text" className="form-control" id="firstName" />
</div>
}
```

I somehow feel this is not the best way to implement it as I need to avoid code repetition. Could someone tell me what is the better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice sintactic sugar for modern JavaScript and React (if you are using React, you must likely have it), you simply add a question mark before the object you're not sure it exists like:

```js
this.state?.testJson?.Names?.length > 0
```

Also, you could have default values of a **nullish variable** like:

```
// names will be an empty array if it doesn't exist or if it's nullish
const names = this.state?.testJson?.Names ?? [];
```

All together is:

```
const names = this.state?.testJson?.Names ?? [];

return(
    names.map(response =>
        <div className="form-group col-md-3" key={response?.nameId}>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">{Liferay.Language.get('first-name')}</label>
            <input
                name="firstName"
                value={response?.otherName}
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="firstName"
            />
        </div>
    ) : ....rest of the code!
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetching inside some cards

```
<div className="row">
      {!names
        ? "Loading..."
        : names.map((name) => {
            return (
              <div className="col">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{name.firstname}</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
    </div>
```